# SQL - Join two queries and also set a default value when there is no match

Tags: sql, join

Is it possible to merge the following two queries and also have a default value `offline` for `status` when it doesn't have entry to match?

#### Example:

```
SELECT
    Objects,
    COUNT(*) AS Objects_count
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    Objects
```

```
---------------------------------
Objects         |   Objects_count
---------------------------------
Unitied_states  |   2           
Germany         |   2           
Turkey          |   1           
Kuwait          |   2
```

#### Second query:

Note: when the status is not equal to 1, there is no entry for that in table2. So in table two we have only entries that are online.

```
SELECT
    Objects, 
    CASE 
        WHEN status = 1 THEN 'ONLINE'
    END AS Status
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    status = 1
GROUP BY
    Objects
```

```
--------------------------
Objects         |   Status
--------------------------
Unitied_states  |   Online          
Turkey          |   Online
```

I want the final output to be something like

```
-------------------------------------------
Objects         |   Objects_count  | Status
-------------------------------------------
Unitied_states  |   2              | Online
Germany         |   2              | Offline
Turkey          |   1              | Online
Kuwait          |   2              | Offline
```

Comment: please tag your SQL engine and provide sample data in tabular form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Your second query's `CASE` expression is redundant because the `WHERE` clause ensures all `status` values will be `'Online'`. Please explain what your second query is actually meant to accomplish.

Comment: Your second query is invalid: the `status` value is not included in the `GROUP BY` clause nor is it part of an aggregate operation. Why does your second query have a `GROUP BY` clause but performs no aggregate operation at all?

Comment: What are the key columns in `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: `Objects` is the key `table1` and `table2`. Btw your solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, by doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

I also assume you want to `JOIN` on the `Objects` column:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( t1.Objects, t2.Objects ) AS Objects,
    COALESCE( t1.Objects_Count, 0 ) AS Objects_Count,
--  t2.Status,
    CASE t2.status WHEN 1 THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END AS status
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Objects,
            COUNT(*) AS Objects_count
        FROM
            table1
        GROUP BY
            Objects

    ) AS t1

    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Objects, 
            status
        FROM
            table2

    ) AS t2 ON t1.Objects = t2.Objects
```

Comment: @User . . . Based on your question `full join` is overkill and not needed for this query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I wrote my answer I wasn't sure if `table1` and `table2` represented distinct subsets of all of the data or not.

Comment: . . The comment was directed at the OP, not at you.  This is a fine approach if needed, but nothing in the question really suggests that it is needed -- there are no `0`s in the sample results, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using `left join` table1 and table2 on `Objects`.

```
select 
    t1.Objects, 
    coalesce(COUNT (t1.*), 0) as  Objects_count,
    case 
        when t2.status = 1 then 'Online'
        else 'Offline'
    end as Status 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.Objects = t2.Objects
GROUP BY 
    Objects,  
    case 
        when t2.status = 1 then 'Online'
        else 'Offline'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.Objects, COUNT(*) AS Objects_count,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM table2 t2
                          WHERE t2.Objects = t1.Objects AND t2.status = 1
                         )
             THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline'
        END) as status
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Objects
```

This returns all rows from `table1` along with the status.

Alternatively, if `table2` has no duplicate rows, you can use a simple `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.Objects, COUNT(*) AS Objects_count,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.Objects) > 0 THEN 'Online' ELSE 'Offline' END) as status
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.Objects = t1.Objects AND t2.status = 1
GROUP BY t1.Objects;
```

Comment: Updated my question with left joins. I want to test your query but I'm unsure how to use alias when there are other left joins. Can you update your answer?

Comment: @user . . . (1) Don't update a question after it has been answered, particularly in a way that invalidates answers.  That draws downvotes on that answers.  (2) You may have syntactically put `left join` into the answer, but the `where` clause just turns it into an inner join.  You should probably ask a new question with appropriate sample data, desired results and explanation.

Comment: Okay I'll revert the question back to its original state.

Comment: Can you update your answer to fit a couple of left joins and then alias? I think a new question asking on how to make it look like your query might bring downvotes.